# Setup different public path in laravel 4 for testing environment

Tags: php, laravel

I have set up a test environment in start.php:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('http://localhost*', '*.dev'),
));
```

Now I want to define a different public path for `local` environment

production:    'public' => **DIR**.'/../../../www/',

local:         'public' => **DIR**.'/../../../www/local',

but the paths.php locates in bootstrap folder instead of app, so how can I set up a different public path?

Comment: There's no need to do this, because of the way that Laravel and environments work, you can just have your testing configuration and testing related items inserted into the bootstrap files you have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same problem few days ago : I needed to change the public directory name from '*public*' to '*www*' for production, as it is on shared hosting and I can't change it.

I searched a way to configure that while sticking to the configuration files system.
Here's how I did it : created a new file */app/start/production.php*, and put inside :

```
if ('production' === $app['env'])
{
    $app->instance('path.public', str_replace('public', 'www', $app['path.public']));
}
```

That file (specific to your environment) is called during the bootstrap process, so this small hack shouldn't cause problems.

The call itself is done in */vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php* on line 256.

Note: this has not yet been tested in production (deployment scheduled this week), but tested for the local environment

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

you have access to the `$env` variable in your `paths.php` (since it just gets included from `start.php`). so you can build in a switch:

```
'public' => ($env == 'local') ? __DIR__.'/../public' : __DIR__ . '/some/where/else/public',
```

works for me in production.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

That's not how environments are supposed to work. Environments allow you to have different configuration values based on the environment your in. As an example, you might use the `native` session driver on your local environment, but on your production environment you want to use the `redis` driver.

The official documentation covers the [configuration of environments](http://four.laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration). When you use environments it's strongly recommended (from a security point of view) to use the machine name rather then a URL.